# ./configure: No such file or directory in GCC

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation, development

I'm trying to make an operating following osdev.org. However, I can't do this without cross-compiler mode in gcc. I'm trying to change the `host` option to `i686-elf-gcc` (this supposedly activates cc mode to that platform), but to do this I must run `./configure`. When I do, I get this error: `./configure: No such file or directory.` What should I do?

**EDIT:**
Here's an image of my gcc folder:

[image]

Comment: You have no `configure` file in the current directory to execute.  Ensure you're in the correct working directory.

Comment: Or show us the directory contents, there might be a `configure.ac` or other autotool stuff?

Comment: @thrig There doesn't seem to be... What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`./configure` is the first script that should be run when you compile a program in a source code form. What you seem to be doing is looking for the `./configure` script in an already installed instance of gcc, namely one under the path `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0`. That directory is created on installation, so a few steps further than calling `./configure`.

What you should begin with is downloading the source code. Then reading the `README` (or similar) and the `configure` script itself. Once you go through these steps, you'll be running the script. (Most likely with some special parameters. Then `make` and then `make install`. And at this point you will be left with a similar directory somewhere as defined, containing you fresh compilation of the program.)

Comment: @Kivitoe I guess this is a guide for you: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler